# How to create a flow in FlowEnt?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I want to create a simple flow that moves and rotates two objects in the scene. I want them to be moved at the same time but with different easings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per their [website](https://flowent.friedsynapse.com/flow#h.1d4v77itfvhb) you can create a flow with the following code.

```
Flow flow = new Flow()
    .Queue(new Tween(2f).SetEasing(Easing.EaseInBack).For(transform1).Move(Vector3.one).Rotate(Quaternion.identity))
    .At(0f, new Tween(2f).SetEasing(Easing.Bounce).For(transform2).Move(Vector3.one).Rotate(Quaternion.identity))
    .Start();
```